# Unable to connect MongoDB server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have tried to connect to MongoDB server using the below-mentioned link but I am getting an error, I have entered the correct password and dbName but it couldn't connect. Can you please help me out?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://test:Test@123@cluster0.cvbne.mongodb.net/example?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,{userNewUrlParser : true, useUnifiedTopology: true},
    err => {
        if(!err)
        console.log ("'mongoddb connection successed")
        else
        console.log ('Error white connecting mongodb : ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined,2))
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://test:Test@123@cluster0.cvbne.mongodb.net/example?retryWrites=true&w=majority`), {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", () => console.log("---Connected to DB!---"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your answer. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the connection is successful or not, you may use callback functions : *on()* and *once()*.

```
const uri = MONGO_URI;

mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });

mongoose.connection.on(
  'error',
  console.error.bind(console, 'connection error: mongodb')
);

mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log(`mongodb at : ${uri}`);
});
```